# How to record face masking with google vision API?

Tags: android, augmented-reality, masking, face

I want to try face masking like *Snapchat* feature on my Android app. I've tried this face masking using Google vision, but I can't find how to record this face masking.

Is there any solution to record face masking?

Comment: any solution for that ?
Iam searching for same

Comment: trust me, no one help!